# Background Image of my website in android is getting small as Soft key comes up on Android device

Tags: android, css, html

I have created a responsive webpage using html and CSS.
I have set the background image as follows:

```
body
{
    background: url('mobile.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

When I test it on android device it looks perfect on screen, but as soon as I click on input box the soft keyboard appears on screen which makes my background image re-size.

How can I avoid image from getting re-sized on softkey appearance?

Answer (score 0):

The background image is resizing because `body` is actually resizing. When the keyboard comes up, the page dimensions resizes accordingly so that you can scroll  around without any content hiding underneath the keyboard. There are some Android keyboards that have a mode where they float on the screen over the content instead of being laid out under the input, but that's out of the web designer's control.

You'd have to use something other than `background-size: 100% 100%;`. For example, if you use `background-size: 100%;` instead, the image will only resize based on available width, so it wouldn't be affected by the decreased vertical space when the keyboard comes up. Do you really need the background image to resize vertically as well?

Comment: Yes i need the image to be set on entire screen.

Comment: Will `background-size: cover` work for your purposes?

Answer (score 0):

When you use percentages, the width and height resizes according to the parent div which could be the body or a top parent div.

Replacing your `background-size: 100% 100%;` with `background-size:cover;` will do the trick

Comment: background-size:cover; makes the image stretch beyond boundary. the image dosent fit properly on android

Comment: Can you kindly attach a screenshot of how it should look like and how the cover looks like please??

Comment: Hi tried adding images bt is suppose it needs reputation to be 10 hence no allowing me add images. Basically what is happening is my image is not setting right width wise. it goes beyond screen i.e the icons in image corner are getting hidden from left

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution :

```
    var isTouch = window.matchMedia("only screen and (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse)");
    if (isTouch.matches) {

        function getHeight() {
            return screen.height;
        }

        function getWidth() {
            return screen.width;
        }

        var oldWidth =  getWidth();
        var oldHeight = getHeight();

        function setBodyStyleWidthAndHieght() {

            try {
                if (oldWidth === getHeight() && oldHeight === getWidth()) {
                    //The device has been flipped;
                    let temp = oldWidth;
                    oldWidth = oldHeight;
                    oldHeight = temp;   
                }

                document.body.setAttribute("style",oldWidth<oldHeight ? "background-size: auto " + oldHeight + "px;" : "background-size:"+oldWidth+"px auto;");     
            } catch (error) {
                document.body.setAttribute("style","background-size:cover;");
            }
        }
        setBodyStyleWidthAndHieght();
        window.onresize = setBodyStyleWidthAndHieght;
    }
```